# Reading RFID tags only once in Zebra Android SDK

Tags: android, rfid, zebra-scanners

I'm working with Zebra's Android RFID SDK and I'm having trouble with inventorying, since tags are not read once as supposed. This is my configuration code

```
 Antennas.SingulationControl s1_singulationControl = reader.Config.Antennas.getSingulationControl(1);
    s1_singulationControl.setSession(SESSION.SESSION_S2);
    s1_singulationControl.Action.setInventoryState(INVENTORY_STATE.INVENTORY_STATE_A);
    s1_singulationControl.Action.setSLFlag(SL_FLAG.SL_ALL);

reader.Config.Antennas.setSingulationControl(1, s1_singulationControl);
```

Session 2 is supposed to be read only once before being RF energized again...

However, it continuouly reads the same tag...

Do I have to set a search mode (eg. Dual target, single target...)? If so, how? If not, what should I do??

Answer (score 0):

You're nowhere setting the singulation control to the reader,
as well as the estimated population time and other values.

The default example from the [manual](https://mans.io/files/viewer/425500/83) would be:

```
// Get Singulation Control for the antenna 1
Antennas.SingulationControl singulationControl =
        reader.Config.Antennas.getSingulationControl(1);

singulationControl.setSession(SESSION.SESSION_S0);
singulationControl.setTagPopulation((short) 30);
singulationControl.Action.setSLFlag(SL_FLAG.SL_ALL);
singulationControl.Action.setInventoryState(INVENTORY_STATE.INVENTORY_STATE_A);

reader.Config.Antennas.setSingulationControl(1, singulationControl);
```

Also see: [`Antennas.SingulationControl`](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-15/apis/reference/com/zebra/rfid/api3/Antennas.SingulationControl.html) and their [Singulation Configuration Tutorial](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/rfid/android/2-15/tutorials/singulation/).

Comment: Hi Martin! Thank you for your answer... I was indeed setting it to the reader, but I forgot adding that to the question...

Comment: There is one hint... which suggests that the values must match the pre-filter settings. This basically means, that `Antennas.SingulationControl` is only one half of the singulation process. And you can't just make up random values, but these need to match the physical reality.

Comment: eg, when having a roll of transponder tags, `setTagPopulation()` depends on the forward speed.